# Join two tables and get the latest date. 

Tags: php, mysql, date, compare, max

Im new to this form and hopefuly I can get some awesome help!

I got three tables

```
1 "companies"
  ID 

2 "log"
  compid
  datum (date)

3 "sales" 
  datumnow (datetime)
  uppdaterad (datetime)
```

I want to compare log and sales and get the latest or the "newest" entry and display a ASC list of companies from table 1 with only one company for each row. (comparing datum, datumnow & uppdaterad and get the highest date value displayed on one row for each ID from companies)

```
#RESULT 
Rover - 2012-01-15
Daniel - 2012-02-01
Damien - 2012-03-05
```

I´ve struggled with this for a few days now and can´t get a hold of the solution. 
App. ANY help! thanx.

Comment: What relates `sales` to the other tables?  Does `sales` also have a `compid` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GREATEST()` to return the most recent date from those three columns.  This assumes you have another column in `sales` that relates to the other tables.  From the structure you show above, the relationship is unclear.

```
SELECT
  companies.ID,
  GREATEST(log.datum, sales.datumnow, sales.uppdatedad) AS mostrecent
FROM
  companies LEFT JOIN log ON companies.ID = log.compid
  /* Assumes sales also has a compid column.  Will edit if new info is posted */
  LEFT JOIN sales ON companies.ID = sales.compid
WHERE log.userid='$userID' AND sales.seller='$userID'
```

For only one row with the max date per company, use a `MAX()` aggregate with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  companies.ID,
  MAX(GREATEST(log.datum, sales.datumnow, sales.uppdatedad)) AS mostrecent
FROM
  companies LEFT JOIN log ON companies.ID = log.compid
  /* Assumes sales also has a compid column.  Will edit if new info is posted */
  LEFT JOIN sales ON companies.ID = sales.compid
WHERE log.userid='$userID' AND sales.seller='$userID'
GROUP BY companies.ID
```

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick! Million thanx!
I forgot to mention one thing. The code you gave me worked perfect except that it gives me all rows =) 

Where do I add "WHERE userid='$userID'" in log.compid 
And "WHERE seller='$userID'" for sales.compid. 

Hope you understand.

Comment: Yes you did =) 
And a final one.. Where to put GROUP BY companies.ID?

Comment: A NEW Question. 

How do I group so i only get one row with the highest date? For each companies.ID
/Thanx

Comment: @user1249956 No GROUP BY is needed in the original query here because you don't have any aggregate functions `SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), AVG()`. To get them in order, `ORDER BY ID`.

Comment: @user1249956 The max date per group has been added above.